# ValueError: Unable to parse string "rock" at position 0

Tags: python, pandas

Hwllo!!Im trying to change the values of a clounm in a dataframe but whenever I do this i get an error.How can I solve this??Thanks in advance!!

```
    spotify_songs['playlist_genre'].replace({'pop':-2,'rock':-1,'rap':0,'r&b':0.5,'latin':1,'edm':2})
    
    spotify_songs['playlist_genre'] = pd.to_numeric(spotify_songs['playlist_genre'])
    
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()
    
    ValueError: Unable to parse string "rock"
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-43-af6d09958a10> in <module>
    ----> 1 spotify_songs['playlist_genre'] = pd.to_numeric(spotify_songs['playlist_genre'])
    
    ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/numeric.py in to_numeric(arg, errors, downcast)
        147         coerce_numeric = errors not in ("ignore", "raise")
        148         try:
    --> 149             values = lib.maybe_convert_numeric(
        150                 values, set(), coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric
        151             )
    
    pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()
    
    ValueError: Unable to parse string "rock" at position 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spotify_songs['playlist_genre'].replace({'pop':-2,'rock':-1,'rap':0,'r&b':0.5,'latin':1,'edm':2})
```

Is not in-place, so the values in `spotify_songs['playlist_genre']` are still the original strings when you call `to_numeric` (I'm not sure why though since you already supposedly replaced the values with integers). This is evident by the error message:

```
Unable to parse string "rock" at position 0
```

`"rock"` clearly can't be converted to a numeric value.

You need to provide `inplace=True` to `.replace`, or re-assign.

```
spotify_songs['playlist_genre'].replace({'pop':-2,'rock':-1,'rap':0,'r&b':0.5,'latin':1,'edm':2},
                                        inplace=True)
```

or

```
spotify_songs['playlist_genre'] = spotify_songs['playlist_genre'].replace({'pop':-2,'rock':-1,'rap':0,'r&b':0.5,'latin':1,'edm':2})
```

A 'proof' the call to `to_numeric` is not required:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['1']})
>> df.dtypes
a    object
dtype: object
>> df['a'].replace({'1': 1}, inplace=True) # note replace=True
>> df.dtypes
a    int64
dtype: object
```